# How to check PHP if user has logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication

How can i check if user is logged in, so the function if(logged_on()) is called when user is logged in the php function is called and showing content for only logged in users like this:

```
<?php
   if(logged_on()) {
       // show profile, edit profile buttons
   }
   else { // show login button or form }
?>
```

I have declared all the session variables to $username and $password etc. but i haven't declared logged_on() function. but i will also add is_admin() function so admin can access non-user content and delete users and pages, and then a confirm_admin() function so users can't access delete-users.php and so on.

Comment: Your question is not clear? "How can i check if a user is "logged in" or has entered a session variable, i want to declare user logged in as this". Please change wordings so that it will be understandable  and also put what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Did you build the logged_on() function ?

Comment: Anant - I will explain a little better, thanks for the tip
Aviz - I haven't, i don't know how to do that

Comment: And your concrete question now is?

Answer (score 1):

Simply with
    if (isset($_SESSION)) { ... }

Else you cane use the "session_status()" method.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

If you want to know if a specific variable is setted:
    if(isset($_SESSION["isLogged"]) { ... }

Comment: thanks, but check the edit i did. it's a little more clear about what i'm trying to achive

Comment: You can declare a variable like $_SESSION["isAdmin"] but I think that it's unsafe. If you have the flag "isAdmin" on database, read this variable from database directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function is_logged() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) return $_SESSION['user_id'];
        else return false;
    }

    if (is_logged()) {
        $user_id = is_logged();

        do_something($user_id);
    } else {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //form submitted
            //check login and password, if they are correct, do this:
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id_from_database;
            //if not correct
            unset($_SESSION['user_id']);

            header('Location: /'); //refresh page
        } else {
            //show login form with button named 'submit'
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but check the edit i did.